# Rust ownership - cannot move due to being "behind a shared reference"

Tags: rust, linked-list, ownership

I am learning Rust and practicing on Linked Lists, whereby I want to get to a solution that doesn't involve a `.clone()` at the end.

Here's the smallest useful MVP code I can come up with ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e0c91c57eba6f6022b165521462cfef6)):

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
fn main() {
    let v: Option<Box<ListNode>> = None;

    println!("{:?}", v);
    let result2 = get_nth_node(v, 3);
    println!("  --> {:?}", result2);
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone, Debug)]
pub struct ListNode {
    pub val: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<ListNode>>
}

fn get_nth_node(head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, n:usize) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    if head.is_none() {
        return None;
    }

    let mut count = 1;
    let mut ptr: &Option<Box<ListNode>> = &head;
    while count < n {
        count += 1;
        match ptr {
            None                    => return None,
            Some(v) => ptr = &v.next
        }
    }
    return (*ptr);
}
```

This yields an error on moving and borrowing:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*ptr` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/main.rs:30:12
   |
30 |     return (*ptr);
   |            ^^^^^^
   |            |
   |            move occurs because `*ptr` has type `std::option::Option<std::boxed::Box<ListNode>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |            help: consider borrowing the `Option`'s content: `(*ptr).as_ref()`
```

I understand why changing the function to return `(*ptr).clone()` works, but it seems superfluous.

My two main questions:

1. What specifically is the shared reference that `*ptr` is behind?
2. Is there a better way, conceptually, to work with this in Rust?

Comment: In case you don't know of it yet, a near-mandatory reading on implementing linked lists in Rust is over [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/). (spoiler: it's hard to get them right)

Comment: If I had more cred I would upvote your comment, @E_net4iscleaningup. Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What specifically is the shared reference that *ptr is behind?

`ptr` is a shared (immutable) reference:

> ```
> let mut ptr: &Option<Box<ListNode>> = &head;
> ```

`*ptr` is behind that reference.

> Is there a better way, conceptually, to work with this in Rust?

Well you could just not work with references since you're taking the list by value and are therefore consuming it:

```rust
fn get_nth_node(mut head: Option<Box<ListNode>>, n:usize) -> Option<Box<ListNode>> {
    let mut count = 1;
    while count < n {
        count += 1;
        match head {
            None                    => return None,
            Some(v) => head = v.next
        }
    }
    return head;
}
```

Alternatively, you could work with refs (that would probably be a better idea really):

```rust
fn get_nth_node(mut head: Option<&ListNode>, n:usize) -> Option<&ListNode> {
    let mut count = 1;
    while count < n {
        count += 1;
        match head {
            None                    => return None,
            Some(v) => head = v.next.as_ref().map(Box::as_ref)
        }
    }
    head
}
```

Comment: Great answer - thanks. In particular around the theme of either working all with references or all without in the function scope. I did get that second solution easily, but ultimately this question came from a programming competition that forced me into a signature with no references.